# How to program to mimic ShareThis in order to share content via Facebook

Tags: facebook, social-networking, sharethis

In my website, I would like to have a facebook icon on each page. Clicking on the icon should mimic the same behavior as in clicking on the facebook icon in ShareThis (http://www.sharethis.com/).

How can I program for that?

Thanks for any pointers and input!

Comment: I did quite a bit of google search, but did not get any clue about how to program.

Comment: google "Facebook sharer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `http://example.com/index.html` in the code below with the current page's location, and `Title` with the title (use %20 instead of a space if the title includes spaces).

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/index.html&title=Title" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Share on FB"</a>
```

You will need to save an icon called `fb.png` in the `images` folder first but plenty are available free to use with a credit link, eg [fatcow.com](http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons)

[source for link](http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/)